# Почему final переменные в java не инициализируются с дефолтными значениями?

Tags: java, final

Почему final переменные в java не инициализируются с дефолтными значениями?

Comment: Потому что спецификация языка требует явной инициализации финальных полей - [JLS 8.3.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.2).